# Analysis sense check: preregister planned contrasts which we wish to conduct even if associated ANOVA is nonsignificant?

Tags: anova, experiment-design, contrasts, false-discovery-rate, planned-comparisons-test

I could use a sense check on my analysis plan for an experimental study which has not yet been run; I will preregister it once I am confident that it is reasonable. There are seven between-participants conditions - call them A, B, C, D, E, F and G - participants in each condition will view a different stimulus, and then complete the same tasks. There are two continuous dependent variables X and Y, and one binary dependent variable Z. The comparisons of interest are as follows:

1. A vs. G (we hypothesize differences between these groups in X and in Z)
2. B vs. G (we hypothesize differences between these groups in X and in Z)
3. A vs. F (we hypothesize differences between these groups in X and in Y)
4. E (a control) vs. A, B, C, and D (we hypothesize that at least one of A, B, C, D, F, G will exceed E for X; likewise for Y; likewise for Z; if so, we would obviously be interested in which group(s) specifically exceed E, but have no super-strong hypothesis with respect to that, so this could be looked at post-hoc)

This is for an academic psychology audience who is probably used to thinking in terms of ANOVAs, and who will be rightly keen to see that we have made efforts to control the false discovery rate, given the number of tests. I would also note that X, Y, and Z are conceptually very different variables that are unlikely to be especially correlated, and that I don't anticipate any issues with the ANOVA assumptions being met based on our experience with these DVs in the past.

My thought was to analyze the data with a total of three separate univariate ANOVAs (the one with Z as the DV would be a binomial ANOVA). So planned contrasts could be preregistered to cover the first 3 bullet points above. For (4), we could follow up any significant ANOVAs with Dunnett's post-hoc tests (or perhaps Tukey's if my collaborators decide that they are willing to accept the loss in power in order to explore comparisons among other conditions beyond the control). So we have a total of 3 ANOVAs with 6 planned contrasts -- totalling 9 primary tests, to which a FDR-controlling procedure such as Benjamini-Hochberg could be applied.

(One wrinkle is that the stimuli in conditions A, B, C, D, and E are all quite different from each other, whereas the stimulus viewed by participants in group G is quite similar to the one in group B, and the stimulus viewed by A is quite similar to the stimulus viewed by group F; I don't see that this should raise any issues, but if this raises red flags for anyone, do please let me know.)

Does this analysis plan sound reasonable, and if not, what alternative would you suggest? I am happy to provide more context if needed - if so please let me know what specifically would be helpful for me to add.

One concern I have is that we are very keen to run the tests implied by bullet points 1-3 even if the overall ANOVAs associated with them do not turn out significant, as we are probably more interested in those hypotheses than in the hypotheses tested by the omnibus ANOVAs. As I (perhaps wrongly) understand it, you still need to actually run an ANOVA to run a planned contrast even if you don't particularly care about its significance, as part of what gives a planned contrast more power than a standard t-test is that the [mean-square error is obtained from the full one-way (omnibus) ANOVA](http://web.pdx.edu/%7Enewsomj/uvclass/ho_planned%20contrasts.pdf). But I am under the impression that generally one does not run planned contrasts associated with an ANOVA if the overall ANOVA is not significant. Perhaps the preregistration should note that if ANOVAs are not significant, then t-tests rather than planned contrasts will be used to make the two-group comparisons? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the study should be designed as dose-response curves: does Z alter the X dose-response relationship, and does Z alter the Y dose-response relationship. The analysis would not be ANOVA which would seem to discard information regarding the dose relationships.

Comment: If I am following your suggestion correctly, the idea here is that factors in the model can affect the relationship between dependent variables instead of influencing a single dependent variable, and so 3 separate univariate ANOVAs will not detect any such patterns, reducing power; one might deal with this via MANOVA (although that won't quite work as we have a binary DV), or - if I am understanding you correctly - with dose-response curves? Am I interpreting correctly?

Comment: (Given that our DVs are quite different from each other and that we are interested in how the condition affects each one independently, with no interest in seeking an underlying construct or a linear composite of the outcome variables, I wasn't sure this would be appropriate (per the arguments of [Huberty & Morris](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/John-Morris-25/publication/232494414_Multivariate_Analysis_Versus_Multiple_Univariate_Analyses/links/5d9b649e299bf1c363fef66e/Multivariate-Analysis-Versus-Multiple-Univariate-Analyses.pdf)...)